# org-mode doesn't display image when LaTeX Image Attributes are included

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, images

I'm facing this problem that when I include some LaTeX specific attributes for my image, then the image doesn't display inside org-mode (although it is displayed fine in my exported LaTeX PDF).

For example, if I include an image like this, the image stop showing inside org-mode:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 7cm
[[img/img2.png]]
```

However if I remove that LaTeX attribute, then it is displaying fine inside org-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

## +ATTR_ORG: :width 300

below the #+ATTR_LATEX: :width 7cm line.

I guess org is showing your image scaled to 7 pixels wide, and it is invisible.

Comment: Thanks. This works absolutely fine. Except that I had to add the suggested attribute `+ATTR_ORG: :width 300`  **BEFORE** the LaTeX attribute `#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 7cm`. Then only it was working. Don't know why it was behaving this way. Could be some problem with my setup.

Comment: ok, I got it backwards. It is not a problem with your setup, org must take the first one, and it uses a regexp to get the width in pixels. it doesn't have any scaling or recognition of units.

Comment: It doesn't require me to add `+ATTR_ORG:` parameter.  May be I am working on the latest version of org mode.

Comment: Is there any attr_org command to crop the images? say I want to disaply only 40% of image from top.

Comment: I don't know of anything like that. you might be able to adapt something in https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax/blob/master/scimax-org-images.el to achieve this, if you can get imagemagick to make the thumbnail you want.